# c:foreach tag not rendering

Tags: c, foreach, tags, jstl

I am using JSTL 1.1.2 and Standard Jar 1.1.2. The c:forEach tag is not rendering any values. I also checked, whether it has values"#{workflowTargetStepSelect.selectedIndex}". And it has 2 values. But the drop down shows me blank for me.

```
          xmlns:c=http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core

          <h:selectOneMenu value="#{workflowTargetStepSelect.selectedIndex}">
                 <c:forEach var="step" items="#{workflowTargetStepSelect.items}"                varStatus="loop">
                       <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{step.prettyNameForRoleType}" itemValue="#{loop.index}" />
                 </c:forEach>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: remove # sign and put $ sign

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this,

```
        <c:forEach var="step" items="#{workflowTargetStepSelect.items}"  varStatus="loop">
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{workflowTargetStepSelect.selectedIndex}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{step.prettyNameForRoleType}" itemValue="#{loop.index}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </c:forEach>
```

And also you can look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880778/setting-value-of-a-hselectonemenu-from-a-for-each).